# UILabel positioning

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

I will have several UILabels laid out horizontally and centered in a view.  Based on the users selection, there will be either 3, 5, or 7 labels.

I am wanting to keep the labels centered in each case.

Example:

```
        L1 L2 L3
     L1 L2 L3 L4 L5
  L1 L2 L3 L4 L5 L6 L7
```

L1 is the same in each case and so on, just showing or hidding the others as needed.  Each line represents a unique case.

Trying to use constraints for each label seems like a big job. Is there a better way to do this???

Comment: This has to be available for ios7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using constraints. So that you don't need to worry about different screen sizes & landscape/portrait.

You can check out the visual format of creating constraints. I find it pretty handy:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html

What I often do is create different sets of constraints and place each set in a separate arrays. When I need to do the swapping, I just remove the whole set and add in another set.

Based on what you want to achieve. I think you can set the constraints like the following:

- make them have the same height/width
- make them align center y with each other
- set the y coordinate of any label
- set the horizontal distance between every two adjacent labels

When you want to display L1 L2 L3, just hide the rest of the labels, and align the center x of L2 to the superview. Similarly, when you want to display L1 L2 L3 L4 L5, just align the center x of L3 and hide the rest of labels

After you change the constraint, you can call `-layoutIfNeeded()` to update the constraint immediately (or place it in an animation block to animate the transition).

Comment: Okay..this makes sense to me now after playing with it more.  Constraints are a bit of a challenge for me.  How do I go about setting a center constraint programmatically on the different Labels as I need?

Comment: Say, in your `viewDidLoad`, you can create a new constraint using

    NSLayoutConstraint* c = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.label1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual  toItem:self.view  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX   multiplier:1  constant:0];
. After you create them and store them, you can remove them, and add them at runtime. Using -addConstraints:(NSArray*)constraints and -removeConstraint:(NSLayoutConstraint*)constraint

Comment: Thank you gyan...that worked great.  One question for understanding...I had set up a center alignment contraints on of the labels via the Storyboard and then had made an outlet connection to the .h file.  I could remove that constraint at runtime, but I could not add it back using the -addcontraint method.  Here's the error:*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: [constraint isKindOfClass:[NSLayoutConstraint class]]'
*** First throw call stack: just curious as to why that didn't work.

Comment: If you drag it from Storyboard, It is default to be a weak pointer. When it is no longer referenced else where, it get released. Maybe removing the weak in the definition(or change it explicitly to strong in objetive-c) will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the new UIStackView available on iOS 9

Comment: Thank you but need for ios7

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something like this. Assuming your labels have already been added to your view.

```
NSArray *labels;
UIView *yourBaseView;

CGRect baseFrame = yourBaseView.bounds;
CGFloat spacer = 10;

CGRect labelFrame;
labelFrame.origin = CGPointMake(baseFrame.origin.x + spacer, baseFrame.origin.y);
labelFrame.size = CGSizeMake((baseFrame.size.width - (labels.count * spacer) - (spacer * 2)) / labels.count, baseFrame.size.height);

for (int i = 0; i < labels.count;++i){
    UILabel *label = labels[i];
    label.frame = labelFrame;
    labelFrame.origin.x += labelFrame.size.width + spacer;
}
```